# Nowhere negative polynomials form a semialgebraic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $P_{d, n}$ be the space of polynomial maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $d$.

Is the subset $S\subset P_{d, n}$ of nowhere negative polynomials semialgebraic?

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but it seems to me that this paper is likely to lead to a positive answer: http://dmle.icmat.es/revistas/detalle.php?numero=4502 .

Comment: In case the link gets outdated, here is the full info on the article I cite: Cukierman, Fernando. "Positive polynomials and hyperdeterminants." Collectanea Mathematica 58.3 (2007): 279-289.

Comment: Yes, this is very well known, it follows immediately for example from the Tarski–Seidenberg theorem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I said in the comments this is very well known: $S$ is the complement of the projection of the semialgebraic set $\{(f,a)\in P_{d,n}\times\mathbb{R}^n:f(a)<0\}$, hence semialgebraic by the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes.

Recall first that the sums-of-squares polynomials of degree at most $D$ and in $n$ variables [form a spectrahedron](https://www.ams.org/notices/201405/rnoti-p492.pdf), and in particular a semialgebraic set.

Now if $f \in P_{d,n}$ is a positive¹ polynomial, then by Hilbert's 17th problem and Artin's solution there are sums-of-squares polynomials $g$ and $h$ such that $f = \frac{g}{h}$. It is possible to [bound](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.2338) the relevant degrees of $g$ and $h$ in terms of $n$ and $d$. (I'm not sure what the best currently known degree bounds are, but the linked 2014 paper gives a tower of five exponentials!)

Thus the $f \in P_{d,n}$ are characterized in terms of the equations $hf = g$ and $h \neq 0$ for sums-of-squares polynomials $g$ and $h$ with a given number of unknown coefficients. Hence $P_{d,n}$ is the projection of a semialgebraic set, and by Tarski's theorem therefore semialgebraic itself.

¹ "Positive polynomial" is the standard term for nowhere negative polynomial.